# Jquery mobile navigation model

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile site and I am using the jquery.mobile library. I am facing problems wrt how jquery.mobile is handling the navigation. It is using ajax for all navigation calls and replacing the DOM.

- I want normal postbacks and do not need the ajax method.
- also, there is a loading `<div>` on all the pages at the bottom. I do not want that. I know its something to do with the ajax request method.

does anyone have any experience with it? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Amit, it is not true that jquery mobile uses ajax for all navigation. You can manually navigate between pages programmatically via

```
$.mobile.changePage('#newpagediv');
```

You can have multiple pages in the html, preloaded and navigate via button click

```
<div id="first" data-role="page">
    <a href="#second">Go to second</a>
</div>

<div id="second" data-role="page">
</div>
```

Comment: how can i make sure that i dont have programmatically do anything. the href's should work as they do natively..

Comment: @amit - stop using jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling it in the $.mobile settings like:

```
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JQM Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) actually specifies:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

Or you could also specify

```
rel=external
```

directly on your  tags to let JQM load the page "normally" and without ajax.

PS: note that in this case the whole JQM will need to re-initialize (as well as your code) on each new page load.

Comment: oh and the div at the bottom is probably because you didn't include the jqm.css stylesheet...